# Splitting field over finite field

Tags: field-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+x^2+1\in \mathbb{F}_2$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$. Suppose that $f$ is a irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ of degree 4. Let $\beta$ be a root of $f$ and $L$ a splitting field of $f$ over $K$.
I am wondering the number of elements in $L$.
I know that $K$ contains 8 elements, $L$ contains all the 4 roots of $f$ and also contains $K$. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every extension of a finite field is normal, so once you adjoin $\beta$ to $K$, you also get all the other roots of $f$. So, $L = K[\beta]$; $L$ has degree $4$ over $K$, so $L$ has degree $12$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$; therefore, $L$ contains $4096$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Degree formula: $[L:F_2]=[L:K][K:F_2]=4\cdot3=12$ if $f$ is an irred. polynomial over $K$. So $2^{12}$ elements.